# ¿Es correcto hacer muchas preguntas en un periodo corto de tiempo?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Me refiero a preguntas que cumplan con los requisitos pero que sean formuladas en un periodo corto de tiempo por el mismo usuario.

Comment: Si el sistema lo permite, es correcto. ¿O tu pregunta es de tipo moral y no técnico? Si es de tipo moral, no lo sé. Si es de tipo técnico, el sistema debe tener algún tipo de control.

Comment: ¿Qué consideras un corto periodo de tiempo? ¿Una cada 20 minutos, cada hora, cada día, ...?

Comment: Por corto tiempo me refería a una pregunta seguida inmediatamente después de otra.

Comment: Como menciona Mariano en su respuesta, los usuarios con reputación menor a 250 pueden realizar una pregunta cada 40 minutos, los de reputación menor a 10 mil, se les pide el CAPTCHA en caso de que publiquen en lapsos menores a 1 minuto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Claro que se pueden realizar muchas preguntas. Las preguntas le dan vida al sitio y son más que bienvenidas.

Por supuesto, se espera que las preguntas sean de buena calidad. Por ejemplo, en casos donde queda claro que el usuario debería haber esperado la respuesta de la primera antes de realizar otra pregunta, probablemente tengan objeciones por parte de la comunidad y no sean del todo bien recibidas.

Además, existen algunos **límites en cantidad de preguntas** para evitar abusos:

- Usuarios con < 250 de reputación, [40 minutos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/5290909) entre preguntas, en toda la red.

  - Usuarios limitados por el Sistema [Anti Reincidencias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/304899), una pregunta por semana.
  - Pueden ser impedidos de formular nuevas preguntas                              por 1 a 7 días, [dependiendo de cómo fueron recibidas sus preguntas previas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited).
- Usuarios con < 10k de reputación disparan al CAPTCHA con menos de 60 segundos entre preguntas.
- Usuarios con >= 10k de reputación disparan al CAPTCHA con menos de 30 segundos entre preguntas.
- En Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault y Math (no está activo en SOes u otros sitios)

  - Máximo de 6 preguntas por día.
  - Máximo de [50 preguntas en los últimos 30 días](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/304899) (contados [desde el momento actual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit#comment353092_89230)).

> Fuente: *[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/304899)*

Se intenta que los usuarios nuevos se familiaricen con el sitio, y no empiecen a hacer preguntas a mansalva. Esto está explicado en [¿Por qué el sistema me esta pidiendo esperar un día o más antes de hacer otra pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

La idea no es limitar la cantidad de preguntas, sino evitar casos de mala calidad, abusos o spam. Si un usuario bien intencionado cae dentro de estos límites, podemos pensar que es un pequeño daño colateral para mantener al sitio bien moderado.