# ¿Seria correcto si realizo una serie de preguntas de forma mas o menos sistematica?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, enseñanza-aprendizaje

Estoy aprendiendo C++ siguiendo un libro. El libro contiene ejercicios, yo los realizo, y en mayor o menor medida mis programas cumplen con lo que se pide en el ejercicio, pero soy consciente de que no son la solución óptima y que hay alternativas mucho mejores. Normalmente en este foro te las dan.

¿Es correcto, desde el enfoque que pretende este sitio, si conforme voy haciendo los ejercicios pregunto aqui una forma mejor de resolverlos, o podria ser considerado como flood?

He visto que solo hay otra pagina que recoge las resoluciones a esos ejercicios concretos cuando he buscado y es una pagina de pago. Tal vez estaria bien que esta funcionara como referencia gratuita, que es el cometido de la misma, ¿no?

Gracias.

PD: No seria ponen los enunciados de los ejercicios sin mas. Sino mostrar mi resolucion y preguntar por una mejor.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es correcto hacer muchas preguntas en un periodo corto de tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1720/127)

Answer (score 10):

Por lo que comentas no estaria mal.. hasta la parte que decis de una forma mejor.

El problema que presenta eso, es a que llamamos una forma mejor. Mejorar la visualizacion del codigo? mejorar el uso de memoria? mejorar la velocidad del codigo?

A veces, todos esos puntos se contradicen entre si (por ejemplo usas menos memoria, pero tu programa es mas lento). En general esta clase de preguntas se aceptan, siempre y cuando digas que es lo que queres mejorar.

Si lo que haces resuelve el problema, entonces el programa esta bien. Mas alla de que se vea feo, o parezca un monton, esta bien.

Hay un sitio particular para resolver estas cosas, que esta en ingles [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: +1 por el enlace al sitio Code Review, que está destinado a ello.

Comment: Creo que viene al caso preguntar: se pueden hacer preguntas usualmente dirigidas a "Code review" aquí en SOes? La respuesta de José Antonio Dura parece implicar que sí

Answer (score 3):

Sí es correcto. Hay un sito para esas preguntas : StackOverflow en Español usando el tag : [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%C3%B3n-de-c%C3%B3digo)

> Esta etiqueta sólo debe ser usada para preguntas que incluyen código
>   que funcione correctamente pero que se desea mejorar u optimizar.

Un caso típico de uso de ese tag es el que planteas. Un programa correcto pero mejorable. Hay muchos aspectos en que se puede mejorar un programa correcto. Optimización de espacio o tiempo, modularidad, legibilidad. Si alguno te interesa más que otros indícalo pues a veces unos se consiguen sacrificando otros.

Poniéndo el código con que has resuelto el ejercicio queda claro el esfuerzo realizado. Una pregunta así debiera ser bienvenida.